# Unitary matrix with unit entries

Tags: matrices

I have got a question and I would appreciate if one could help.

Is there any unitary matrix that absolute value of its entries are one?

Comment: $[1] {}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. what about higher dimensions?

Comment: No, because the columns of the matrix have norm $1$.

Comment: A permutation matrix.

Answer (score 0):

For an $N\times N$ matrix, just take the discrete Fourier transform matrix $W=[w_{ij}]$ with elements
$$
w_{ij}=\omega^{ij}/\sqrt{N}
$$
and omit the normalization factor $N^{-1/2}$. The constant $\omega$ is the Nth root of unity, i.e. $\omega=e^{-2\pi\sqrt{-1}/N}$.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix